# Cant upgrade to argparse 1.4.0 on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to set up Google assistant on Raspberry Pi 3 with Matrix creator.
On installing Google Assistant SDK [guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/install-sample) cant get through this command:

> python -m pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]
>   It returns

```
google-assistant-library 1.0.0 has requirement argparse<2,>=1.4.0, but you'll have argparse 1.2.1 which is incompatible.
```

I'm in virtualenv --no-site-packages.

But, when i try to upgrade argparse using below command, I get

> Can't uninstall 'argparse'. No files were found to uninstall. Successfully installed argparse-1.4.0

```
pip install --upgrade argparse

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple Collecting argparse   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f2/94/3af39d34be01a24a6e65433d19e107099374224905f1e0cc6bbe1fd22a2f/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl Installing collected packages: argparse   Found existing installation: argparse 1.2.1
    Not uninstalling argparse at /usr/lib/python2.7, outside environment /home/pi/ga
    Can't uninstall 'argparse'. No files were found to uninstall. Successfully installed argparse-1.4.0
```

Comment: Are you running this command in a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes I'm running in virtual env made with no site packages

Comment: If you run pip freeze, which version of argparse do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Argparse is maintained as a separate package here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse Which is where pip is going to collect it.

But

As of Python >= 2.7 and >= 3.2, the argparse module is maintained within the Python standard library. For users who still need to support Python < 2.7 or < 3.2, it is also provided as a separate package....

So, you are getting the error because it is part of the standard library, but also available to install via pip if you are using a version of Python for which it isn't.

If you really need to install 1.4.0 try this:

1. Download the [[gzip]](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/dd/e617cfc3f6210ae183374cd9f6a26b20514bbb5a792af97949c5aacddf0f/argparse-1.4.0.tar.gz)file, **not the wheel**, from the pypi downloads page
2. Uncompress the archive and open a terminal in the argparse-1.4.01 folder
3. Run python setup.py install (See the 'Install' section of first link)

And check you now have the correct version (hopefully):

1. Open Python shell
2. .>>> import argparse
3. .>>> argparse.**version**
   '1.4.0'

Good luck :)